# mysql if not there in table1 then take from table 2

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my db in which table1 is temporary and table2 is permanent. Now i need to write the query like, if the number of matched rows in  table1 is equal to 0 then take the results from table2. Is there any possibility in mysql to do this? If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN t1.field <> 0 THEN t1.field ELSE t2.field END) 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `UNION`

```
SELECT ID 
FROM table1 
WHERE somecondition
UNION
SELECT ID 
FROM table2 
WHERE somecondition
```

Comment: @tsabz, it will be slower than a join statement. If there is a way to join the two tables on some condition, it will be better, ofcourse than a union. But the op's question isn't clear enough. But I think you have to use union in this case to get the desired results as the op wants.

Comment: Hmm, as the OP said, table1 is a temp table, and table2 is the permanent one. With that, I presume that the tables's structure are the same (ofc, I can't be sure about that as it's clearly not said).

Answer (score 1):

THis will work..

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN count(column) > 0 THEN COUNT(column)
    END,

    CASE
        WHEN count(column) = 0 THEN (
                                      select COUNT(col2) from table2
                                    )
    END
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

if the data in both tables is the same, just union both queries, you will automatically get from one or the other.